# How to echo the target attribute of custom menu in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code composes a custom menu:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <?php
          $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically( 'Menu' ); 
          foreach($menu as $toplevel):
            $hasChildren = !empty($toplevel['children']);
        ?>
          <li<?php if($hasChildren) echo ' class="dropdown"'; ?>>
            <a href="<?php echo $toplevel['url'] ?>"<?php if($hasChildren) echo ' class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"'; ?>>
              <?php echo $toplevel['title'] ?>
            </a>
            <?php if($hasChildren): ?>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <?php foreach($toplevel['children'] as $child): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $child['url']; ?>"><?php echo $child['title']; ?></a></li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
              </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </li>
        <?php
          endforeach;
        ?>
        </ul>
```

But this code do not retrieve the `target` attribute. So, if this is  checked:

[image: "Open link in new tab" checkbox]

the above code will ignore the setting and it will keep opening in the same tab. **What should I do in order to fetch the target value of the menu item?** I tried using `$child['target']`, but this field does not exist...

### Update

This is the code of `wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically`:

```
function wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically( $menu ) {
  $menu_items        =  wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu );
  $hierarchical_menu = array();

  foreach ($menu_items as $item) {
    if( !$item->menu_item_parent ) {
      $hierarchical_menu[$item->ID]['title'] = $item->title;
      $hierarchical_menu[$item->ID]['url'] = $item->url;
      $hierarchical_menu[$item->ID]['attr_title'] = $item->attr_title;
    } else {
      $hierarchical_menu[$item->menu_item_parent]['children'][$item->object_id]['title'] = $item->title;
      $hierarchical_menu[$item->menu_item_parent]['children'][$item->object_id]['url'] = $item->url;
    }
  }

  return $hierarchical_menu;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `get_post_meta($child['ID'],'_menu_item_target',true)` to get the target attribute of the menu item.

#### UPDATE:

To be able to access $child['target'] property you should change your `wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically` function by fetching this property inside ***if...else...*** statement:

```
if( !$item->menu_item_parent ) {
    ...
    $hierarchical_menu[$item->ID]['target'] = $item->tartget;
} else {
    ...
    $hierarchical_menu[$item->menu_item_parent]['children'][$item->object_id]['target'] = $item->target;
}
```

Comment: The `$child['ID']` is always `null`. I used `var_dump` on each child, and noticed that they don't have their ID, so the call gets resolved to `get_post_meta(null, '_menu_item_target', true)`. I tried calling the menu items as `wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically( 'Menu', array("ID") );` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Show the code of the function **wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically**. Is that function from your **functions.php** file or from any plugin?

Comment: I did not develped this theme, so I thought that this function was  just an deprecated WordPress function without documentation. But you are right, it is inside functions.php. I will update my question in order to include it's code.

Comment: @Metalcoder, To be able to access $child['target'] property you should change your `wp_get_nav_menu_items_hierarchically` function. I've updated my answer above. Look at it for details.

Comment: You nailed! Thanks!